# JAVA Writing Gray Scale JPEG Image (dependency on JDK version?)

Tags: java, image-processing, jpeg, raster

I'm a beginner in JAVA language and I need to use a code (Writing GRAY scale JPEG images).
I searched quite long time, but I cannot figure out what is the problem now.

```java
public static boolean writeImage(String inputFileName, String outputFileName, int[][][] imageData)
{
    BufferedImage inputImage = MyImageReader.readImageIntoBufferedImage( inputFileName );
    if ( inputImage == null )
    {
        System.out.println(" Could not open input image.");
        return false;
    }

    BufferedImage outputImage = new BufferedImage( inputImage.getWidth(), inputImage.getHeight(),
                                                   inputImage.getType() );
    WritableRaster outputRaster, inputRaster;
    inputRaster = inputImage.getRaster();
    outputRaster = inputRaster.createCompatibleWritableRaster();

     int band = 0;
    int numbands = outputRaster.getNumBands();

    int height, width;
    height = outputRaster.getHeight();
    width = outputRaster.getWidth();
    int[] pixelData = new int[ 1 ];

    for ( int y = 0; y < height; y++ )
        for ( int x = 0; x < width; x++ )
        {
            for ( band = 0; band < 1; band++ )
            {
                pixelData[ 0 ] = imageData[0][y][x];
            }
            outputRaster.setPixel(x, y, pixelData );
        }

    outputImage.setData( outputRaster );

    File outputFile = new File( outputFileName );
    try
    {
        if ( !ImageIO.write( outputImage, "jpg", outputFile ))
        {
            System.out.println("Could not find image format for output image.");
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        System.out.println("Could not write output file.");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

I'm using above code.
The code seems create a WritableRaste by copying the property from input jpeg file,
so the output jpeg file will have same size.

What I'm doing is do some image processing on gray scaled raster values
and save it as a jpeg file.

When I tested it with simple 4x4 case, the result is as follows.

Input array to be saved in (Height, Width) coordinate

1   2   3   4

5   6   7   8

15  16  17  18

25  26  27  28

When I load saved file, it showed in (Height, Width) coordinate

2    3   4   5

3    4   5   6

15   15  16  17

25   26  27  28

How is this possible? I cannot figure out what is wrong.
The image reader is proven to be safe.
I'm running on JDK 1.7 from Oracle but the original code may written in past.
But I hope this won't be the problem.

Thank you!

Comment: I can't really say without some sample data. Did you debug and see? Also Why do you have a for loop for just one iteration? `for ( band = 0; band < 1; band++ )
            {
                pixelData[ 0 ] = imageData[0][y][x];
            }
`

Comment: because, the original one intended to accept multiple bands but I don't need it. So I suppressed it to be 0. I did same thing in MATLAB using imwrite(Matrix, 'filename' 'jpg') it showed similar results. Am I doing something wrong? I assumed that the Array[height][width] can be saved as jpg file (by some encodings)

Comment: Problem must be in the loop or the data being passed to the function. As far as I can tell nothing stands out as being wrong in the loops. But it's hard for me to tell without debugging.

Comment: Did you try going through the code with a debugger??

Comment: One thing I did was to check the values to be passed, to set Pixel data. I can't check the imageBuffer (I have to learn how to do it). But I suffered same thing in MATLAB. Can I really write gray scale jpeg images by sending 2 dimensional array, that represents values at the index?

Comment: In matlab, when I load image and save it to matrix (uint8) and write the same matrix to other file, fine. But when I create a different matrix (uint8) and tried to write jpeg file using imwrite(Matrix, file); It showed exactly same as above. I have no idea how to manage gray scale image

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use 3rd party libraries and decided to leverage [imgscalr](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/software/imgscalr-java-image-scaling-library/) (Apache 2, open sourced and tiny - one class) you could chop out all the complex code in the middle of your implementation and it would look like this:

```
import org.imgscalr.Scalr.*;

public static boolean writeImage(String inputFileName, String outputFileName)
{
    BufferedImage inputImage = MyImageReader.readImageIntoBufferedImage( inputFileName );
    if ( inputImage == null )
    {
        System.out.println(" Could not open input image.");
        return false;
    }

    // This replaces everything in the middle of your original impl.
    BufferedImage outputImage = apply(inputImage, Scalr.OP_GRAYSCALE);

    File outputFile = new File( outputFileName );
    try
    {
        if ( !ImageIO.write( outputImage, "jpg", outputFile ))
        {
            System.out.println("Could not find image format for output image.");
            return false;
        }
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        System.out.println("Could not write output file.");
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

The key being the [apply](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/downloads/software/imgscalr/javadoc/org/imgscalr/Scalr.html#apply%28java.awt.image.BufferedImage,%20java.awt.image.BufferedImageOp...%29) method call (To apply the pre-defined [GRAYSCALE](http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/downloads/software/imgscalr/javadoc/org/imgscalr/Scalr.html#OP_GRAYSCALE) op to the image).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But I figured out even I use the Scalr library, I see the same result. What I want to do is simply, save 2D array as jpeg file. I assumed that jpeg file will write uint values to each cell given by 2D coordinate. So I hope that if I assigned a value 255 to coordinate (0,0) and saved it, then when next time I load it the same value should be retrieved at (0,0) but it is not.